# Include a calculated expression in a case statement

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

How Can I use the expression I named QTY available in my case statement?

```
cast(((iloc.qty_on_hand) - (iloc.qty_allocated) - (ilocss.qty_non_pickable) - 
(ilocss.qty_quarantined) ) / ( item_uom.unit_size ) as decimal (10,2)) AS 
[QTY available],

case when (iloc.qty_on_hand) <= (iloc.inv_min) then (iloc.inv_max) - 
('QTY available') else 0 end as [Build]
```

Comment: subquery/CTE or copy-paste

Comment: Not sure I understand, Could you show me what it would look like in my case statement? Im not sure on the syntax